# How can I uninstall setuptools?

Tags: python, linux

I can't uninstall setuptools. How come?

```
$ sudo pip uninstall setuptools
Can't uninstall 'setuptools'. No files were found to uninstall.


$ sudo pip install setuptools
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
```

How can I uninstall setuptools?

Comment: `pip` *requires* `setuptools`... how would it uninstall it?

Comment: Auto-recursively is how. That and some magic Fortran dust.

Comment: Looks like an XY problem. Why are you trying to uninstall setuptools?

Answer (score 1):

Considering that current Python versions are shipped **with** setuptools, pretty sure you *shouldn't* remove it.

And since `pip uninstall setuptools` doesn't work (thankfully), you could try just deleting the `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\setuptools`, or equivalent, folder. (On *nix systems: `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`.)

Disclaimer: this is a very bad idea, `pip` may not work at all afterwards.